# GUI Design on Android - Dropdown menus

Tags: android, user-interface

I wish to design an android based application, which will have typical drop down menus as in common desktop based GUI system.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your drop down menus in android are called Spinners. You can find more information for this here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

How about expandable list view?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html